# How to mute Gmail thread on Android?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

I muted the message on web browser on my pc. I can see Muted tag is applied to the thread. I no longer receive notification on this thread from browser on pc. But I keep getting notifications on my Android. I am not the only person on the to/cc list of its messages. I searched old questions and answers. They mentioned a `Done` button. But this button is gone on the Gmail android app I'm using. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Long-press or open the conversation.
2. Click the 3-dot, select Mute.

Comment: On the message I keep getting notifications from, there is not a Mute button. On other messages, I see the button. I guess it's a bug in Gmail App or sth.